# iOS UITableView - crash when inserting new section with error message which may indicate that I should call moveSection:toSection: method

Tags: ios, uitableview

I reload, insert and delete table view's rows and sections in a single begin/end update block. I do not call `moveSection:toSection:` nor `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` method.

I am aware that deletion and reloading of existing cells are being executed first, regardless of the order of method calls in update block. I do not insert rows for the new section that is inserted. Also, I am updating data source before table view update block.

Deletion and reloading work just fine for me, but I have a problem with inserting new sections. I got error messages of type:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 5.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

It is interesting that I do not delete or reload any table view's rows and sections in the corresponding table view update block. Also, there is 1 row in all sections that come before section 5. New section was inserted at index 0. So it seems to me that I might be missing `moveSection:toSection:` method call..?

I couldn't find more complex examples of simultaneous inserting, deleting and reloading rows and sections in a single update block on Internet, so I would really appreciate any suggestions and links to the examples that could guide me how to handle more complex table view updates.

Comment: After a batch of updates, the TV calls (amongst other things)`numberOfRowsInSection` to confirm the new number.  For section 5, your datasource method is returning **1**, but the TV knows that previously it was **3** yet you have not inserted/moved/deleted any rows.  It doesn't add up.  Would need to see the code for the TV datasource methods and the insert/delete code to diagnose it further.

Comment: May I ask a theoretical question - how come that table view does not recognize that new section was added somewhere in the middle and that all sections with indexes greater than added section's index should be moved? I checked it out, data source was updated correctly. P.S. There are a lot of lines of code so I would like to keep it theoretical in this thread, if possible...